# How to do bitwise OR between two arbitrary long VARBINARY(MAX) values in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**Motivation:**

I would like to have a trigger that would do something when any of the text fields of any table is updated or inserted into.

The code must not hard code any table knowledge. I.e. it should work on arbitrary tables.

**Where did I get so far**

1. DDL trigger on `CREATE_TABLE` that adds a `FOR INSERT,UPDATE` DML trigger for the new table
2. A `_ColumnMask` table mapping 1-based integers to the respective VARBINARY(MAX) masks compatible with the `COLUMNS_UPDATED` format.

Having the `_ColumnMask` table and some `aaaCulture` table, I am able to write the following query:

```
;WITH aux AS (
    SELECT (MAX(column_id) + 7) / 8 mask_len
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('aaaCulture')
)
SELECT c.name, column_id, CASE WHEN pad.zero IS NULL THEN cm.mask ELSE cm.mask + pad.zero END mask
FROM sys.columns c 
JOIN aux ON 1 = 1
JOIN sys.types t ON t.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
JOIN _ColumnMask cm ON cm.n = c.column_id
LEFT JOIN _ColumnMask pad ON pad.n = aux.mask_len - (c.column_id + 7) / 8
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('aaaCulture') AND (t.name LIKE '%char' OR t.name LIKE '%text')
ORDER BY c.column_id
```

Yielding

```
name        column_id   mask
Text1       2           0x020000000000
Text2       4           0x080000000000
Text3       6           0x200000000000
Text4       8           0x800000000000
Text5       10          0x000200000000
Text7       14          0x002000000000
Text8       16          0x008000000000
Text9       18          0x000002000000
Text10      20          0x000008000000
Text11      21          0x000010000000
Text21      24          0x000080000000
Text22      26          0x000000020000
Text23      28          0x000000080000
Text24      30          0x000000200000
Text25      32          0x000000800000
Text26      34          0x000000000200
Text27      36          0x000000000800
Text28      38          0x000000002000
Text29      40          0x000000008000
XRefCode    42          0x000000000002
Text12      44          0x000000000008
```

For example, suppose I update fields `Text9` and `Text23`:

```
UPDATE dbo.aaaCulture SET Text9 = 'haha', Text23 = 'xoxo'
```

The respective `COLUMNS_UPDATED` value as reported by the DML trigger is:

```
0x000002080000
```

Indeed, according to the aforementioned query result:

- `Text9` has the mask of `0x000002000000`
- `Text23` has the mask of `0x000000080000`

Doing bitwise OR between the two masks yields exactly `0x000002080000`

Hence I seem to have all the pieces of the puzzle in order to be able to recognize that `COLUMNS_UPDATED()` includes any text columns. Except, I have no idea how to do it **efficiently** (I could write some kind of an ugly WHILE loop, I suppose).

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1**

We update the database by adding a DB upgrade step to a certain sql script (under the version control). My goal is to prevent the devs from checking in any DB steps that update or insert into any text fields in any of the xyzCulture tables, including those created by those new DB steps. Let us not discuss, why we have xyzCulture tables in the first place. There are there, sigh, it is given.

I may resort to preventing update to any field whatsoever in those tables, but first I want to really understand how hard it is to be more specific.

Comment: Probably a silly question, but are you sure you definitely need to restrict yourself to *only* when any *text* column is updated? Determining if the row has been modified at all is a bit easier. Also, I have to ask what your motivation is for making the trigger table-agnostic at runtime -- as you've seen, code like that is pretty horrid to write. Generated code would still be horrid, but a lot easier to achieve.

Comment: Added an edit. Maybe I am doing it wrong, maybe I will resign at the end and just prevent any update. But I want to try doing it selectively first.

Comment: With that edit, another option to consider is adding column-level security instead. As each table is created, identify the fields and execute dynamically generated statements of the form `DENY UPDATE ON T(c) TO [upgradeaccount]`. This would have the advantage of not adding overhead on every statement, but it may be hard or impossible to get to work depending on the existing rights of `upgradeaccount`.

Comment: The upgrade account is omnipotent, currently. Can I still deny update and then at the end of the script allow it back? The purpose is to prevent accidental updates. It is not really about security, so even if devs are able to allow the access themselves in their DB upgrade step, this is not a concern here.

Comment: I need to prevent an accidental attempt to update/insert even if it would not happen actually (because of the WHERE condition, for instance). Devs should not attempt to insert localized messages into the DB upgrade script.

Comment: In that case, yes, a DML trigger is your only option. And may God have mercy on your soul. :-) I'm almost, but not entirely sure that any solution will either involve a `WHILE` or a `JOIN` on a `nums` table (possibly only as a CTE) and will not, by any stretch of the imagination, be efficient. A custom CLR function could be made efficient, if you are allowed to deploy that.

Comment: Well, it is turned on at the beginning of the script and turned off at the end. Plus, it is only in effect when somebody truly attempts to modify those tables, which should not happen in the mainstream case. (And yes, I am using recursive CTE to create the _ColumnMask table :-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helas, I could not come up with anything other than the following implementation:

```
CREATE FUNCTION VarBinaryBitwiseOR(@x VARBINARY(MAX), @y VARBINARY(MAX))
RETURNS VARBINARY(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pos INT = 0
    DECLARE @res VARBINARY(MAX)
    DECLARE @tmp VARBINARY(MAX)
    WHILE @pos + 8 <= DATALENGTH(@x)
    BEGIN
        SET @tmp = CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(@x,@pos + 1,8) AS BIGINT) | CAST(SUBSTRING(@y,@pos + 1,8) AS BIGINT) AS varbinary(MAX))
        SET @res = ISNULL(@res + @tmp, @tmp)
        SET @pos = @pos + 8
    END
    IF @pos + 4 <= DATALENGTH(@x)
    BEGIN
        SET @tmp = CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(@x,@pos + 1,4) AS INT) | CAST(SUBSTRING(@y,@pos + 1,4) AS INT) AS varbinary(MAX))
        SET @res = ISNULL(@res + @tmp, @tmp)
        SET @pos = @pos + 4
    END
    IF @pos + 2 <= DATALENGTH(@x)
    BEGIN
        SET @tmp = CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(@x,@pos + 1,2) AS SMALLINT) | CAST(SUBSTRING(@y,@pos + 1,2) AS SMALLINT) AS varbinary(MAX))
        SET @res = ISNULL(@res + @tmp, @tmp)
        SET @pos = @pos + 2
    END
    IF @pos + 1 <= DATALENGTH(@x)
    BEGIN
        SET @tmp = CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(@x,@pos + 1,1) AS TINYINT) | CAST(SUBSTRING(@y,@pos + 1,1) AS TINYINT) AS varbinary(MAX))
        SET @res = ISNULL(@res + @tmp, @tmp)
        SET @pos = @pos + 1
    END
    RETURN @res
END
```

It only works when the `DATALENGTH` of both arguments is the same, which is my case exactly.

So, it is both slow and not general purpose (the `datalength` must be the same).